# How can I run a Shell when booting up?

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, boot

I am configuring an app at work which is on a Amazon Web Server.

To get the app running you have to run a shell called "Start.sh"
I want this to be done automatically after booting up the server

I have already tried with the following bash in the User Data section (Which runs on boot)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/ec2-user/app_name/"
sh Start.sh
echo "worked" > worked.txt
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? Does your EC2 instance already have `/home/ec2-user/app_name/Start.sh` installed (eg via AMI)? What version of Linux is on the AMI (eg Amazon Linux)? Did you check the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: probably a supervisor could help, I would suggest  https://immortal.run or check other implementations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Actually, none, the app starts up properly, but I cannot get it to start automatically on boot. I have already tried making a soft link from the /etc/init.d directory and Cronjobs, even editing the rc.local file.

Is a RHEL 7.4 and the cloud-init-output.log its actually empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts provided through User Data are only executed the first time the instance is started. (Officially, it is executed **once per instance id**.) This is done because the normal use-case is to install software, which should only be done once.

If you wish something to **run on every boot**, you could probably use the [cloud-init **once-per-boot** feature](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#scripts-per-boot):

> Any scripts in the `scripts/per-boot` directory on the datasource will be run every time the system boots. Scripts will be run in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hi @SantiagoDiaz, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.